# mysql order by then setting a value for the newest date

Tags: mysql, perl, email, variables

I am currently making a program that will send an email if the date of a persons last entry was over (some time frame). my table is laid out like this:

```
employee   | dept. | date       | other | 
bob        | 1     | 2012-05-29 | abc   |
bob        | 1     | 2012-07-15 | xyz   |
jon        | 2     | 2012-05-29 | abc   |
```

(i have sorted with mysql by employee then date)
so for example, for bob i want to automatically assign a variable to the date 2012-07-15 because that is the date of his last entry. then based on the current date i want to send an email if that time in between submissions has been to long. My question is how to i assign a variable to the last date of each person in the table? I am also open to different better ways of doing this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the latest date for each employee, something like this will work.

```
SELECT employee
     , MAX(`date`) AS latest_date
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY employee
 ORDER BY employee
```

---

Addendum,

As simbabque points out, this works for getting the latest date, but does not return the `other` value.  There are a couple of approaches to getting that result set.

If we are guaranteed that the (employee,date) is UNIQUE (for example. by a unique constraint), we can return other columns on the row that has the latest date with a query like this:

```
SELECT t.employee, t.`date`, t.other
 FROM mytable t
 JOIN ( SELECT r.employee, MAX(r.`date`) AS latest_date
         FROM mytable r
        GROUP BY r.employee
      ) s
   ON s.employee = t.employee
  AND s.latest_date = t.`date`
ORDER BY t.employee
```

If we aren't guaranteed that (employee, date) is unique, this query would not suffice. But there are a couple of approaches to addressing that issue.

Comment: ok thanks this helps a lot, although how do i make it so each latest_date has a variable name that is attached to the date and the employee?

Comment: This will work if @BluGeni only wants the date. But if he wants to send the *other*-vakue in his email, it won't.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in Perl. Credit for the SQL query goes to @spencer7593.

If you are not familiar with [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm) I suggest you take a quick look. Also look at [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.021/lib/DBD/mysql.pm) to see how the *datasource* (DSN) is created.

You basically need to connect to the DB, prepare your query, execute it and fetch the results. You can then use them to send your email.

Here's a quick example that does not include the actual email sending:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
require 'script_that_has_custom_email_sub.pl'; # or use a module or whatever

# create the database handle
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost", # <-- DSN
                       'username', 'password')
            or die $DBI::errstr;

# prepare the query to get a statement handle
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(<<__SQL__
SELECT employee
     , MAX(`date`) AS latest_date
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY employee
 ORDER BY employee
__SQL__
);
$sth->execute; # send the query to the mysql server

# fetch each row of the result as a hashref
while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
  # access $res with the keys employee and latest_date from the query
  # and send the mail
  &custom_send_email_sub($res->{'employee'}, $res->{'latest_date'});
}
$sth->finish;
```